# Проверка username на уникальность в базе firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

С помощью данного куска кода сохраняется username человека который он вводит

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseUser.getUid());
                    HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                    hashMap.put(EXTRA_USERNAME, strUsername);
                    hashMap.put(EXTRA_SEARCH, strUsername);
                    reference.updateChildren(hashMap);
```

Но как сделать проверку? Если например такой username уже есть, то человека просят ввести другой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашел ответ)

```
final DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
                    final HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

                    Query query = reference
                            .orderByChild("username")
                            .equalTo(strUsername);
                    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()>0) {
                                //username found
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Введите другое имя", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }else{
                                // username not found
                                hashMap.put("username", strUsername);
                                reference.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).updateChildren(hashMap);
                            }

                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
```